# Azure app service Configuration ambiguity

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, azureportal

I've uploaded an asp.net core app with VS 2019 publish, and targeted the app `netcoreapp2.2`.
The app worked perfectly, but when checking some performance issue, I've noticed that in Azure portal-Configuration-General settings, the app stack settings was `.NET` (not .net core), and version is V4.7.

This raises 2 questions:
1. How is it even working...?
2. Why VS deployment process wasn't configured with the settings displayed in publish section?

VS publish settings:
[image: VS publish settings]

Azure settings:

[image: Azure settings]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET Core 2.x can target .NET Core or .NET Framework. ASP.NET Core apps targeting .NET Framework aren't cross-platform—they run on Windows only. Generally, ASP.NET Core 2.x is made up of .NET Standard libraries. Libraries written with .NET Standard 2.0 run on any .NET platform that implements .NET Standard 2.0.

When you published to the .NET Core 2.2 runtime app you would always get the following warning message:

```
"There was a problem starting MyProjectName on MyWebAppServiceName. Your application requires the .NET Core 2.2.0 runtime, but Microsoft Azure App Service only support the following versions:.
```

One way to fix this problem is by changing the deployment mode to `self-contained` in the publish settings, which will **allow the application to carry its own runtime**."

Refer to this similar [case](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e0859e05-8a2f-41d4-a24c-4445b8646fdd/azure-web-app-gt-runtime-stack-should-i-choose-quotnet-core-22quot-or-quotaspnet?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview).

Edit:

When you create webapp on portal, you could go to arm template to get the stack setting which is set as `CurrentStack: dotnetCore`. But when you publish project on VS, it could net set the runtime.

So, it may a VS issue that you could give feedback or you could create webapp on Azure first which set runtime as .Net Core and publish project to it using VS.

Comment: Thanks @Joey for your answer. When you say I'll always get the warning message, is this refering to situations where my Azure web app service is already set to a .net framework ('classic'), or do you mean something else? I ask because I haven't seen this error message.

Comment: Thanks for that. That's clear my question of the differences between VS publish config and settings in portal.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by updating the following lines in .sln
from:

```
Visual Studio Version 16
VisualStudioVersion = 16.0.29613.14
```

To:

```
# Visual Studio Version 16
VisualStudioVersion = 16.0.30011.22
```